# Best way to print an iPython notebook

Tags: printing, jupyter-notebook, pdflatex

What is the best way to print an iPython notebook (`.ipynb`) that contains a lot of figures/plots, photos, and code that would appear with a horizontal scroll bar? I've tried converting them to HTML, slides, PDF, etc, but neither has produced a decent output. For example, the slides have super-large font/zoom such that one page has no more than 5 lines of text in it. I've tried GitPrint, but that's only good for markdown (`md`) files. I've tried converting `ipynb` to `tex` and using `pdflatex` to convert to PDF, but there are a lot of errors and I keep getting stuck with a question mark prompt (`?`). When I hit enter through them, the output doesn't contain the photos. So what is the best way here? I don't care about the extension, only that it looks good (like the `ipynb`) on paper.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `nbconvert` to convert the ipynb file into HTML and the question will be: How to pretty print a HTML file? And print a HTML file would be much easier compared with printing a ipynb file.

Command is like this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html filename.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a decent solution as I was stuck with the same problem. For an aesthetically pleasing print-out of the Jupyter notebook (.pdf format) for the usage of study and learning (as lecture slides), I recommend take a print-out using your web-browser (Chrome: Print=Ctrl+P).

**Outcome**: an aestheically pleasing document, containing all codes, pictures as embedded within a Jupyter notebook.

*tl:dr* Avoid any conversion within the Jupyter notebook option; print straight out of web-browser.

Comment: directly printing the chrome page is not a decent solution. As it is not properly formatted for fitting into proper page layout

Comment: This does not work well in JupyterLab (1.2) but works in classic notebook. In JupyterLab select Help -> Launch classic notebook, then from your *browser* menu (e.g. 3 dot menu) choose print and print to pdf. This will paginate with proper margins.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and flexible way is to use CSS.
For example, put the following code in a cell and run. I will remove all code blocks and output blocks. In this way you can control what you want.

```
%%html
 <style>
 div.input {
      display: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    div.output_prompt {
      display: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    div.text_cell_render {
      padding: 1pt;
    }

    div#notebook p,
    div#notebook,
    div#notebook li,
    p {
      font-size: 11pt;
      line-height: 135%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .rendered_html h1,
    .rendered_html h1:first-child {
      font-size: 16pt;
      margin: 7pt 0;
    }

    .rendered_html h2,
    .rendered_html h2:first-child {
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin: 6pt 0;
    }

    .rendered_html h3,
    .rendered_html h3:first-child {
      font-size: 13pt;
      margin: 6pt 0;
    }

    div.output_subarea {
      padding: 0;
    }
 </syle>
```